Proguard configuration to keep members with an annotation that has parameters
We are obfuscating our project with Proguard and are using picocli for some command line tools.  We have Java code something like the following
@picocli.CommandLine.Option(names = { "--argument", "-a" }, description = "An argument", required = true)  
private String testArgument;

and we want to exclude 'testArgument' from the obfuscation as this field name can be shown to the user by picocli.  The classes defining the different picocli options and commands do not share an interface or common extension point and I don't really want to add one if I can help it.  With the following configuration I can keep the field if I change the annotation in the code to Java's @Deprecated
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @java.lang.Deprecated <fields>;
}

which makes me think we can't be too far away but it seems that the parameters in the annotation are causing the problem and we can't quite figure out the syntax to incorporate them into the proguard configuration.  We have tried things like
@picocli.CommandLine.Option* <fields>;
@picocli.CommandLine.Option... <fields>;
@picocli.CommandLine.Option?*? <fields>;

none of which have produced the result we need.
Is there configuration we're missing which will keep these field names or does Proguard not support annotations with parameters?
Thanks for any suggestions

Hi @Dan, I was curious to find an answer for this, and posted this question in Proguard forum and got an answer. Apologies for posting this question without your consent. Here is the link - https://community.guardsquare.com/t/proguard-configuration-to-keep-members-with-an-annotation-that-has-parameters/4113.

@VasanthSubramanian thank you, I raised the question on the GitHub but hadn't found the community.  That answer does work, thanks again.

Answered here https://community.guardsquare.com/t/proguard-configuration-to-keep-members-with-an-annotation-that-has-parameters/4113
I should have recognised that Option is an innerclass.
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @picocli.CommandLine$Option <fields>;
}

